# My site can't open links in mobile

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a strange issue on this page where the image links open okay on desktop but for some reason, tapping the images does nothing in mobile. iphone and android! The links should open in mobile!

Page link http://gp.serverlake.com/press/

Any one to spare some thoughts on this?

HTML THAT PULLS IMAGES FROM CUSTOM FIELDS

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb"><a href="<?php echo $imglink; ?>" class="thumbnail" target="_blank">

                    <img class="img-responsive margin-tp" src="<?php echo $img;?>" alt="" style="margin-top: 25px;" /></a>

                    <div class="name text-center"><?php echo $title;?></div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Some of those links point to PDF files, which may result in such issue. Try to click links that point to images - and they should work perfectly.

How can we open PDF files in browser from iPhone - it is another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was easy. Z-index on the image did the trick!

```
.thumb .thumbnail img {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99999;
}
```